# Django - complex calculations in the template

Tags: django, django-templates

As far as I understand, there's no way to do math including django variables in the template, for example

```
<td>{{variable_1}} + {{variable_2}}</td>
```

People recommend to do the calculations in the views, but my concern is that we should use servers-side just to transmit data from server to client - that's it. All the calculations should be done using client computer power. The other option might be doing calculations in javascript, particularly jquery, after the page load, but the downside is that data is rendered with a lag in those cases when calculations are very complex. What is the best practice here and most balanced soltion ?

Comment: VTC as primarily opinion-based. It seems to me that in your opinion this should happen client-side and/or in templates. That is fine. It is Django's rather strong opinion that it should not, to the extent that they built their framework around this opinion and deliberately limited such uses in their templates. As a side note, you seem to be conflicted about this yourself, as at first you say it should be client-side then later worry about the render lag caused by performing it client-side.

Comment: Well, I bother about client-side lagged rendering because I do the calculation AFTER the page has been loaded, otherwise how can you loop through the table

Comment: This is so much at fault. Doing the calculations in template does not take the processing power to the client. It simply shifts it to another point in the framework, but we are still at the server side. This looks like a question for the sake of asking. If not, consider angular. I doubt that in the vast majority of applications there will be so many calculations in the template that will matter significantly.

Comment: Wtower's comment needs to be upvoted multiple times. The OP has a fundamental misunderstanding of Django if he thinks that templates are rendered on the client.

Answer (score 2):

[django-mathfilters](https://github.com/dbrgn/django-mathfilters) provides a series of template tags just for this purpose. Install you will be able to perform limited calculations in your template via filter tags. From the docs:

```
{% load mathfilters %}

<h1>Basic math filters</h1>

<ul>
    <li>8 + 3 = {{ 8|add:3 }}</li>

    <li>13 - 17 = {{ 13|sub:17 }}</li>

    {% with answer=42 %}
    <li>42 * 0.5 = {{ answer|mul:0.5 }}</li>
    {% endwith %}

    {% with numerator=12 denominator=3 %}
    <li>12 / 3 = {{ numerator|div:denominator }}</li>
    {% endwith %}

    <li>|-13| = {{ -13|abs }}</li>
</ul>
```

If you need further functionality, you would easily be able to [make your own tags](http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html) to perform any needed calculations.

Comment: Also, @Wtower's comment above is important and a fundamental concept; template rendering is not a client side operation.